# Passing multidimensional int array from Java to C (and back) using SWIG

Tags: java, arrays, swig

I need to invoke from Java a C function that takes, as input, a bidimensional int array. The same array is used by the C function to provide its output. I modeled the bidimensional array as an array of int* using the "array_functions" directive available with SWIG:

```
%array_functions(int*, intArray);
```

As expected, SWIG generates the SWIGTYPE_p_p_int type plus following two helper functions:

```
public static int[] intArray_getitem(SWIGTYPE_p_p_int ary, int index) {
  return contrastJNI.intArray_getitem(SWIGTYPE_p_p_int.getCPtr(ary), index);
}

public static void intArray_setitem(SWIGTYPE_p_p_int ary, int index, int[] value) {
  contrastJNI.intArray_setitem(SWIGTYPE_p_p_int.getCPtr(ary), index, value);
}
```

I am able to allocate from Java the SWIGTYPE_p_p_int class and to write into it. However, as soon as I try (from Java) to access the content of the array (like in the following example), I get a segmentation fault exception:

```
            SWIGTYPE_p_p_int abc = contrast.new_intArray(1000);
            contrast.intArray_setitem(abc, 1, new int[100]);
            // invoke the C function passing it 'abc'
            int[] def = contrast.intArray_getitem(abc, 1);
```

As far I can see, the C function is able to read and write 'abc', without any problem. Thus I tried a second code, where I took off the C part, and I still get the same error:

```
            SWIGTYPE_p_p_int abc = contrast.new_intArray(1000);
            contrast.intArray_setitem(abc, 1, new int[100]);
            int[] def = contrast.intArray_getitem(abc, 1);
```

Comment: I guess this happens because of alignment (different alignments in Java and native code). I would create a native method that gets/sets a given element addressed by two coordinates. But remember that accessing your array that way can be a bad idea because JNI calls are relatively expensive.

Comment: Thank for your hint. As far as I can see, the alignment part is handled correctly by SWIG. I would suspect more a problem related to the way the pointer to the array is passed by Java to C, but I am unable to explain why it does work if I write in the array and not if I read